# ThreadExceptionEventHandler and invoking delegates

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, exception

If I assign a `ThreadExceptionEventHandler` to `Application.ThreadException`, why when I invoke a delegate method using a control on the main application thread are any exceptions thrown by that delegate not triggering the event handler?

i.e.

```
static void Main()
{
    ...

    Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);    
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Error.Write("A thread exception occurred!");            
}

...

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread syncThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThrowException));
    syncThread.Start();
}

private void ThrowException()
{
    button1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        // Not handled by ThreadExceptionEventHandler?
        throw new Exception();
    }));
}
```

The context on this is that I have a background thread started from a form which is throwing an unhandled exception which terminates the application. I know this thread is going to be unreliable since it is network connectivity reliant and so subject to being terminated at any point, but I'm just interested as to why this scenario doesn't play out as I expect?

Comment: That's an interesting question. You would think that the thread exception event handler would be called because the exception occurs on the UI thread.  Perhaps you need to set the unhandled exception mode?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to help - I'll add it to the example code though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` instead , to catch exceptions that occur in threads not created and owned by Windows Forms

You should definetly see [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) to clarify this issue

Comment: Although this does fire, I can't seem to actually do anything about the exception at that point except log it - and the application exits. Since I don't really care much about this background process failing I don't want to kill the whole process.

Comment: In that case wrap method wich executes in thread into `try-catch`  block